# Parse XML on BlackBerry

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I need to have URL contents as String in blackberry. As you know blackberry is not supported Java Native URL class. Please give me one more good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about SAX. It's a good friend. An example tutorial:

http://jsinghfoss.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/sax-parsing-revising/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to get my URL contents as String. Please give me good example once more.

Comment: Look at this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Make-an-HTTP-Connection-to-get-a-Content-of-URL/m-p/97817/message-uid/97817/highlight/true#U97817 also please read about the different parameters sent to the URL (after the Query String) in order to define if it should connect via WiFi, BES, BIS-B, TCP, et al

Comment: Hi Plata! How you doing? I am back to Blackberry project now. Can you please explain what is the meaning of your helping statement "also please read about the different parameters sent to the URL (after the Query String) in order to define if it should connect via WiFi, BES, BIS-B, TCP, et al"

Comment: Also please explain, Should we mention about which connectivity method we are going to use. Because the example you quoted above have no any parameters like what I understand from your comment. Thanx